# How to get summation in C?

Tags: c, arrays

How to make a program to read elements from input like:

> 1 3

and give me the summation of that:

> 4

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char x[3];
    scanf(" %c",&x);
    printf("%d\n",x[0]+x[2]);
}
```

Comment: Only the title said C++; the tags and the code said C.

Comment: @LAD And if someone writes this code as c++ code, the are certainly not writing the right code.

Comment: @Elmasry What are you expecting the program to do? Can you describe that with words?

Comment: What do you want to do if the input is `1 2 3 5 7 11`?  Or a longer sequence?  You're probably going to need a loop to read new values, and then add them up in a variable initialized to zero.  Will you need to preserve the numbers for other uses, or can you discard them after they're read?  That will affect whether you need an array or not.  If you have to have an array, you get into questions of 'how big an array' too — it's easier if you don't need to keep the numbers for later use.

Comment: Are you aware you are summing characters rather than integers?!

Comment: You should get a good book or online equivalent. You don't learn C by trial and error.

Comment: @CroCo characters are not summed, integers are. `char` is an integer type. In `printf("%d\n",x[0]+x[2]);` the operands are promoted to `int` before summing, and since `char` values sent to `printf` are promoted to `int` too, the compiler might keep the sum as `int` rather than convert it back to `char` and then promote it to `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: but the fact that the code tries to read using `%c` instead of `%d` means that if the user types `0`, the output will be based on `x[0]` containing 48, not 0 (assuming ISO 8859-x or Unicode or other ASCII-based encoding).  But that is counteracted by the fact that `x[2]` is not initialized, so the output value is indeterminate at best — there's undefined behaviour in the program.  (And using `&x` in the `scanf()` call passes a `char (*)[3]` instead of a `char *` — the OP gets away with it, but doesn't know what coincidences they're depending on.)

Comment: @WeatherVane I’m aware of that but summing characters  internally represented as integers may not yield the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

In your approach you seem to read in a string and treat several positions of that string as numbers. Besides the fact that there are several mistakes in implementing this approach, the main thing actually is that you've taken the wrong approach. Drawbacks (not all, just some) are: you only consider numbers of exactly one digit; you assume that user input is exactly mapped to your array with exactly one "blank" position between the numbers of interest (as you access `x[0]+x[2]` with hard-coded indexes `0` and `2`); you are limited to exactly two "numbers" to be summed up; ...

I'd rather scan integral values (i.e. using `%d` and data type `int`) within a loop until one enters something that is not a valid number. This solves all of above mentioned issues:

```
int main() {

    int sum=0;
    int num=0;
    printf("type in numbers to be summed up (type a non-number to exit):\n");
    while (scanf("%d",&num)==1) {
        sum += num;
    }
    printf("sum: %d\n",sum);
}
```

Intput/Output:

```
type in numbers to be summed up (type a non-number to exit):
10 20 30 x
sum: 60
```

Comment: The blank in the format string eats zero or more white space characters, including newlines.    Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I did not use a blank in the format string, because `%d` ignores leading white spaces anyway, doesn't it? But yes, one may continue entering numbers after having pressed "enter". That's why a CTRL-D or a non-digit value is necessary to terminate input.

Comment: I'm not objecting to your code; I'm objecting to your comment 'you assume that a user inputs exactly one space in between' — the original code doesn't make that assumption because it uses `" %c"` (a surprising and good choice on the part of the OP, if the OP was really wanting to read characters and not numbers).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: ah - OK. The "assuming one space in between" arises from the formula used in the final `printf`. Added a comment in the answer.

Comment: Yeah — that `scanf()` statement in the original is all round a bit weird.  It inputs a single character, and passing `&x` means the pointer is of type `char (*)[3]` when the calling code supplies it; `scanf()` treats it as `char *` and the OP gets away with that.  Neither `x[1]` nor `x[2]` is ever set to anything, so the calculation is using undefined values and hence undefined behaviour.  It's often tricky to criticize coherently that which is not coherent to start with.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things missing here.

For one thing, you're only reading one character with `%c`.  You're storing it in `&x`, which, though confusing, is technically legal: since it's a sequence of `3` `char`-sized elements in memory, `&x` is a valid character address.  However, `x[1]` and `x[2]` remain uninitialized; you're not setting them anywhere.

Secondly, you're not converting it to an integer value so it still has the value of the character '1' not decimal 1.  `'1' + '1'` (note single quotes) will evaluate to `49 + 49` (note lack of quotes), 49 being the ascii equivalent to the character `'1'` -  very different from the decimal value `1`.

Finally, you're only summing the first and third character (the latter, being uninitialized, has an unknown value, certainly not one from your input).  The second character is not a part of the final result.

If you want to read 3 `integers`, you should scan for `int`s, not characters, and you should scan for the number of them you wish to read. That would allow you to read numbers above 9 correctly.

But perhaps you *do* want to scan for *one digit* at a time; in which case, you'll certainly want to convert each digit *character* to it's *integer* equivalent.  Since the digits `0` to `9` are contiguous and in ascending order in ascii, you can simiply subtract `'0'` from the character to get its decimal equivalent ( `'1' - '0' == 1`, `'9'-'0'==9`, etc.)  But for this to work, you must ensure that you really have read a *digit* and not just any `char`.  You might do so by verifying that its value was between `'0'` and '`9`', inclusive.

Regardless of whether you wish to sum integers or digits, you'll want to ensure you're reading *each* value you're going to sum before computing the final sum.

It might make more sense, given your use case, to keep scanning for ints in a loop until you run out of ints on the input stream.  You don't really need to store them each; you can read one int at a time and add it to a running total.

Putting that all together, you might end up with something like this.  Take these ideas and implement your running sum, and you'll have what you want for characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char c; // we'll store our input here as we go
  while( scanf(" %c", &c) == 1 ) { //one thing matched
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9'){ // it's a digit
      printf("Read %c, decimal value of digit is %d\n", c, (int)(c-'0') );
    }else {
      printf("Invalid digit %c\n", c);
    }
  }
}
```

I run like this:

```
$ gcc -o t t.c && echo '1 2 3 4 5' | ./t
Read 1, decimal value of digit is 1
Read 2, decimal value of digit is 2
Read 3, decimal value of digit is 3
Read 4, decimal value of digit is 4
Read 5, decimal value of digit is 5
```

Change to `scanf("%d")` like described below to read multi-digit integers instead, changing the code accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int c; // we'll store our input here as we go
  while( scanf(" %d", &c) == 1 ) { //one thing matched
    printf("Read %d; wasn't that easy?\n", c);
  }
}


$ gcc -o t2 t2.c && echo '1 2 3 4 5' | ./t2
Read 1; wasn't that easy?
Read 2; wasn't that easy?
Read 3; wasn't that easy?
Read 4; wasn't that easy?
Read 5; wasn't that easy?
```

That approach can read any integer repesentation up to the min/max size of `int`, including multiple digits and even negative numbers:

```
$ gcc -o t2 t2.c && seq -1 -10 | ./t2
Read -1; wasn't that easy?
Read -2; wasn't that easy?
Read -3; wasn't that easy?
Read -4; wasn't that easy?
Read -5; wasn't that easy?
Read -6; wasn't that easy?
Read -7; wasn't that easy?
Read -8; wasn't that easy?
Read -9; wasn't that easy?
Read -10; wasn't that easy?
```

Comment: What static array are you talking about?

Comment: Scanf handles multiple inputs in a single line. No need for looping.

Comment: The static array of 3 chars is defined atop main.  You might be used to thinking of character arrays as strings,  but if you're passing it as the destination for a `%c` scan, it isn't really a string.

Comment: True @CroCo, and if some exact number were expected that would be perfectly valid.  A finite scan pattern can't match an indefinite input length, but that was a bit of an embellishment in the use case, granted.

Comment: @DanFarrell: that's not what most people normally mean by 'static array'; a `static` array is one prefixed with `static`.  Also, strictly, the `&x` argument to `scanf()` is a `char (*)[3]` — compounding the confusion.

Comment: That's not a static array and its elements aren't initialized to 0. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
int n1;
int n2;
scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);

int sum = n1 + n2;
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

If you want to add more than two numbers together, you could try:

```
printf("Enter how many numbers you want to add:\n");
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);

int sum;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int in;
    scanf("%d", &in);
    sum += in;
}

printf("%d\n", sum);
```

---

**Note:**

At first the answer had C++ in the title and so I answered with C++ like this:

If you don't mind using `cin` and `cout`, you could try:

```
int n1;
int n2;
cin >> n1 >> n2;
cout << n1 + n2;
```

Comment: Although the title said C++, the tags said C (only).  I fixed the title, though it somewhat invalidates your use of C++ in your answer – sorry.  However, you've also somewhat changed the way you're handling the problem.  Tricky!

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry about putting you to the trouble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No problem, I am adding some C code to my answer.

Comment: You need quote marks as in `scanf("%d, %d", &n1, &n2);` and in `printf("%d\n", sum);` Please test an answer before you submit it. After all we expect the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from question posters. So why are hasty answers exempt?

Comment: @WeatherVane I would test it and I usually do, except that my IDE isn't working at the moment. I need to fix it.

Comment: Don't drink and drive either.

Answer (score 0):

Running this program with n integers will return their sum by iterating from argv[1] to argv[n].  argv[0] is the name of the program.

Example:

./sum 1 3 returns 4

Code:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int sum;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
        sum += (int)strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);
        }

        printf("%d\n", sum);

    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Invalid number of arguments\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Strictly, you've changed the problem — "make a program to read elements from input".  You should also add some explanation of what you've done.

Comment: Why are you casting `NULL`? It appears that you don't like compiler warnings, and that's not what you should do about them.

Comment: ./sum 1 3 returns 4, ./sum 1 3 4 returns 8, etc.  I have also fixed the Null cast.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array and a loop. This is a simple method.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int sum=0, allocation[5],i,num;
printf("enter the number of elements");
scanf("%d",&num); // how many numbers are there??
printf("Enter the elements");
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
 scanf("%d",&allocation[i]);  //allocate the elements in the array say 3,4,5
 sum=sum+allocation[i];      
//0+3, sum=3
//3+4, sum=7
//7+5, sum=11
}
printf("Sum= %d",sum);  //print Sum=11
getch();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

    int num1,num2;

    printf("Enter two numbers");

    scanf("%d %d", &num1 &num2);

    printf("Sum is = %d", num1+num2);

    return 0;
}
```